# LaTeX Beamer -- Horizontal alignment of tables

Tags: beamer

I'm working on a beamer template and I'm stuck with trying to find out how to customize the horizontal alignment of tables. More precisely, I'm trying to add tables with a caption, but I'm trying to avoid them being centered at the same time. Let's say I have a case where I want my table to be left or right-aligned on my current slide. For reports or any other written documents, horizontal centering makes sense and I'm aware of that, however in beamer it is sometimes important to make best use of the (little) available space on a slide.

Furthermore I'd be very happy if there was a possibility to specify the absolute positioning of a table on a slide, e.g. by using coordinates.

I cannot find a way to avoid using the table environment (\begin{table}...). It seems for me that this environment is necessary for LaTeX to enable the creation of a table caption. However, I suspect I'm wrong on this.
An additional constraint from my side is that I don't want to use the columns environment (\begin{columns}...) to achieve a horizontal positioning of my table.

Here's a MWE:
(For my needs I like to use the NiceTabular environment)

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=table,12pt]{beamer}
% compile in pdfLaTeX

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
    \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2pt}

\definecolor{tableGreyHeaderBg}{RGB}{135,135,135}
\definecolor{tableGreyCellBg}{RGB}{227,227,227}
\definecolor{tableGreyLines}{RGB}{135,135,135}
\definecolor{tableGreyCellFg}{RGB}{127,127,127}

    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Tables}
        \begin{table}[htbp!]%
        \captionsetup{width=.35\textwidth}
        \noindent\caption{This is a table caption.}%
        \begin{NiceTabular}[c]{wc{1.0cm}wc{1.0cm}wc{1.0cm}wc{1.0cm}}[rules/color=tableGreyLines]
        \CodeBefore
            \rowcolor{tableGreyHeaderBg}{1}
            \rowcolors{2}{}{tableGreyCellBg}
        \Body
            \toprule[1.5pt]
            \RowStyle{\color{white}}H1 & H2 & H3 & H4  \\
            \arrayrulecolor{white}\toprule[1.5pt]
            \RowStyle[nb-rows=*]{\color{tableGreyCellFg}}Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3 & Cell 5 \\
            \midrule
            Cell 5 & Cell 6 & Cell 7 & Cell 8 \\
            \midrule
            Cell 9 & Cell 10 & Cell 11 & Cell 12 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular}%
        \end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any help or any hints how I can solve this problem. Thank you and

Best Regards
Konrad

Comment: Please don't ask multiple unrelated questions in one post. It would be better if you would split caption justification and table positioning into two separate posts.

Comment: Sorry about that. Trying to keep this in mind for future posts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a table environment to add a caption. The caption package, which you already load, has the `\captionof{...}{...}` macro which allows you to add captions without a table (or figure) environment.

However for the special case of beamer, which by default does not number captions, you could just set them as normal text, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=table,12pt]{beamer}
% compile in pdfLaTeX

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
    \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2pt}

\definecolor{tableGreyHeaderBg}{RGB}{135,135,135}
\definecolor{tableGreyCellBg}{RGB}{227,227,227}
\definecolor{tableGreyLines}{RGB}{135,135,135}
\definecolor{tableGreyCellFg}{RGB}{127,127,127}

\newcommand{\mycaption}[2]{%
  {%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{caption name}%
    \usebeamerfont*{caption name}%
    \csname#1name\endcsname%
    \usebeamertemplate{caption label separator}%
  }%
  #2\par
}

    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Tables}
        \mycaption{table}{This is a table caption}
          
        \begin{NiceTabular}[c]{wc{1.0cm}wc{1.0cm}wc{1.0cm}wc{1.0cm}}[rules/color=tableGreyLines]
        \CodeBefore
            \rowcolor{tableGreyHeaderBg}{1}
            \rowcolors{2}{}{tableGreyCellBg}
        \Body
            \toprule[1.5pt]
            \RowStyle{\color{white}}H1 & H2 & H3 & H4  \\
            \arrayrulecolor{white}\toprule[1.5pt]
            \RowStyle[nb-rows=*]{\color{tableGreyCellFg}}Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3 & Cell 5 \\
            \midrule
            Cell 5 & Cell 6 & Cell 7 & Cell 8 \\
            \midrule
            Cell 9 & Cell 10 & Cell 11 & Cell 12 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular}%
        
        \raggedleft
        \mycaption{table}{This is a table caption}
          
        \begin{NiceTabular}[c]{wc{1.0cm}wc{1.0cm}wc{1.0cm}wc{1.0cm}}[rules/color=tableGreyLines]
        \CodeBefore
            \rowcolor{tableGreyHeaderBg}{1}
            \rowcolors{2}{}{tableGreyCellBg}
        \Body
            \toprule[1.5pt]
            \RowStyle{\color{white}}H1 & H2 & H3 & H4  \\
            \arrayrulecolor{white}\toprule[1.5pt]
            \RowStyle[nb-rows=*]{\color{tableGreyCellFg}}Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3 & Cell 5 \\
            \midrule
            Cell 5 & Cell 6 & Cell 7 & Cell 8 \\
            \midrule
            Cell 9 & Cell 10 & Cell 11 & Cell 12 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Sam,
thank you for your answer :)
Is it possible to add a numbering to \mycaption, too (e.g. Table 1, Table 2, etc.)?
BR

Comment: @Konrad Your question does not have numbered captions. If you need numbered captions, you should ask a new question with all the specifics you actually need.

Comment: Ok. I'll accept your first comment as the answer of this question and open a new question. Thank you and BR :)